# why does the accept attribute not filter the types specified in this example in chrome and firefox?

Tags: html, input, mime-types

I have a web form where i have a file input with accept attribute but the filebrowser doesn't filter the files by the mimetype specified.

I tested on chrome and firefox browser on windows 10.

Here you can see a code example:

```html
<html>
<body>

<form>
  <!-- Pdf works fine -->
  <input type="file" name="pdf" accept="application/pdf"> 
  <!-- Zip doen't work -->
  <input type="file" name="zip" accept="application/zip">

  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works on mac osx. can you try uploading a pdf file in your input and then type `document.getElementsByName('pdf')[0].files[0].type` in your javascript console. And do you have all files or just certain ones? What if you replace it with `.pdf` instead?

Comment: @Kaiido i'm sorry, the pdf file input works fine. It's the zip input file which doesn't works

Comment: Both work on osx and I don't have a win10 under hand right now to test. Once again, what does *"deosn't work"* means? No files are selectable? All files are selectable? Can you do the same procedure I asked you to do by replacing `pdf` with `zip`?

Comment: The mime types change a little between browsers so that may be the case... For example in IE it should be application/x-zip-compressed and in Firefox application/octet-stream. But why put the mime type and not just accept=".zip"?

Comment: @Kaiido, in the zip file input, all files are selectable. I also tested it on the Firefox browser on Ubuntu and it works fine but not on windows 10

Comment: And what is returned when you type `document.getElementsByName('zip')[0].files[0].type` in the console after you did select a zip file? Maybe you need to also set `application/x-zip-compressed` for this OS (`accept="application/zip, application/x-zip-compressed`)